# Rails 4 - Validates uniqueness with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have these three models:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :surname, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }

  has_many :permissions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stores, through: :permissions
end
```

Store:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true

  has_many :permissions
  has_many :users, through: :permissions
end
```

Permission:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
end
```

How can i validate the uniqueness of the `user.email` based on the `store.id`?

Comment: Don't you validate email uniqueness in user model? Shouldn't email be a unique identifier for users?

Comment: I need to allow users to be able to subscribe to multiple stores with the same email.

Comment: It makes more sense that a user can subscribe to multiple stores without register multiple accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

You should validate the uniqueness of the users email in `User`. And validate the uniqueness of the `user_id` and `store_id` in `Permission`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end

class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: 'store_id'
end
```

This allows a user to have permissions for multiple stores - but does not allow duplicates. In general when linking records together use id's - not something like emails.

Comment: As @wesley6j allready stated - it makes no sense that users should be able to create multiple accounts with the same email - you allready have a many to many assocation that will allow a single user account to be linked to any number of stores.